# How can I resize, minimize, maximize or close Window in the MVVM WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, resize, window

I want to create a Metro style Window, hide original Border, so I need resize Window ([ResizeWindow](http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=256) but he doesn't use MVVM) and create some Buttons to minimize, maximize and close Window, With MVVM. But there're not `SourceInitialized`, `Cursor`, `WindowStatus`, etc. I know these are Window's.

There're 3 correlative files:

```
MainWindow.xaml
MainWindow.xaml.cs
MainViewModel.cs
```

**`My questions`**

1. Do I need resize, minimize, maximize or close Window in ViewModel?
2. If so, how can I achieve this?
3. If not, whether it violate MVVM pattern?

**`Update`**

After a night, I find that I unnecessarily consider the ClickEvent of the CloaseButton, just call `this.Close()` is OK. If need to do sth. after click ColoseButton(or close app), just call the ClosedEvent or the ClosingEvent of the Window.

Comment: 1. close maybe, rest no; 2. search for close and MVVM; 3. no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can offer the following: leave operations that are done from View on the side of `View`. Operation with the `Window` should be placed in a special class `WindowBehaviours` that would be available from XAML, like that:

Operation `Close`:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Controls:WindowBehaviours.Close" Value="True" />
</Trigger>
```

Operation `Hide`:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Controls:WindowBehaviours.Hide" Value="True" />
</Trigger>
```

This uses `ToggleButton` because he has property `IsChecked` accessible via a trigger.  These properties - attached depending properties.

Listing of `WindowBehaviours` class:

```
public static class WindowBehaviours
{
    // Close the Window
    public static void SetClose(DependencyObject target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CloseProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseProperty =
                                              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Close",
                                              typeof(bool),
                                              typeof(WindowBehaviours),
                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnClose));

    private static void OnClose(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue))
        {
            Window window = GetWindow(sender);

            if (window != null)
            {
                window.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    // Hide the Window
    public static void SetHide(DependencyObject target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(HideProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HideProperty =
                                              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Hide",
                                              typeof(bool),
                                              typeof(WindowBehaviours),
                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnHide));

    private static void OnHide(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue))
        {
            Window window = GetWindow(sender);

            if (window != null)
            {
                window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            }
        }
    }

    // Full the Window
    public static void SetFull(DependencyObject target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(FullProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FullProperty =
                                              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Full",
                                              typeof(bool),
                                              typeof(WindowBehaviours),
                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnFull));

    private static void OnFull(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue))
        {
            Window window = GetWindow(sender);

            if (window != null)
            {
                window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the Window in Normal
    public static void SetNormal(DependencyObject target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(NormalProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalProperty =
                                              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Normal",
                                              typeof(bool),
                                              typeof(WindowBehaviours),
                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnNormal));

    private static void OnNormal(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue))
        {
            Window window = GetWindow(sender);

            if (window != null)
            {
                window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
        }
    }

    // Get the Window
    private static Window GetWindow(DependencyObject sender)
    {
        Window window = null;

        if (sender is Window)
        {
            window = (Window)sender;
        }

        if (window == null)
        {
            window = Window.GetWindow(sender);
        }

        return window;
    }
}
```

Samples of ToggleButtons:

`CloseButton`

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonWindowClose" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">                           
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />                                    
                    <Border x:Name="BorderClose" Background="Beige" BorderThickness="0" Width="22" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" />
                    <Path x:Name="CloseWindow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ToolTip="Close window" Width="18" Height="17" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#2D2D2D" Data="F1 M 26.9166,22.1667L 37.9999,33.25L 49.0832,22.1668L 53.8332,26.9168L 42.7499,38L 53.8332,49.0834L 49.0833,53.8334L 37.9999,42.75L 26.9166,53.8334L 22.1666,49.0833L 33.25,38L 22.1667,26.9167L 26.9166,22.1667 Z " />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="CloseWindow" Property="Fill" Value="#C10000" />
                        <Setter TargetName="BorderClose" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Controls:WindowBehaviours.Close" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`HideButton`

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonWindowHide" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Border x:Name="BorderHide" Background="Beige" BorderThickness="0" Width="22" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,32,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" />
                    <Path x:Name="HideWindow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ToolTip="Hide window" Width="14" Height="19" Margin="0,0,36,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#2D2D2D" Data="F1 M 42,19.0002L 34,19.0002L 34,43.7502L 24,33.7502L 24,44.2502L 38,58.2502L 52,44.2502L 52,33.7502L 42,43.7502L 42,19.0002 Z " />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="HideWindow" Property="Fill" Value="#0094FF" />
                        <Setter TargetName="BorderHide" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Controls:WindowBehaviours.Hide" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`FullScreenButton`

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonWindowFull" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Border x:Name="BorderFull" Background="Beige" BorderThickness="0" Width="22" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,58,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" />
                    <Path x:Name="FullWindow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="19" Height="19" Margin="0,0,60,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#2D2D2D" Data="F1 M 30.25,58L 18,58L 18,45.75L 22,41.75L 22,50.75L 30,42.75L 33.25,46L 25.25,54L 34.25,54L 30.25,58 Z M 58,45.75L 58,58L 45.75,58L 41.75,54L 50.75,54L 42.75,46L 46,42.75L 54,50.75L 54,41.75L 58,45.75 Z M 45.75,18L 58,18L 58,30.25L 54,34.25L 54,25.25L 46,33.25L 42.75,30L 50.75,22L 41.75,22L 45.75,18 Z M 18,30.25L 18,18L 30.25,18L 34.25,22L 25.25,22L 33.25,30L 30,33.25L 22,25.25L 22,34.25L 18,30.25 Z ">
                    <Path.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Name="FullWindowToolTip" Content="Full window" />
                    </Path.ToolTip>
                </Path>
            </Grid>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="FullWindow" Property="Fill" Value="#0094FF" />
                    <Setter TargetName="BorderFull" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Controls:WindowBehaviours.Full" Value="True" />
                    <Setter TargetName="FullWindow" Property="Data" Value="F1 M 54.2499,34L 42,34L 42,21.7501L 45.9999,17.7501L 45.9999,26.7501L 53.9999,18.7501L 57.2499,22.0001L 49.2499,30.0001L 58.2499,30.0001L 54.2499,34 Z M 34,21.7501L 34,34L 21.75,34L 17.75,30.0001L 26.75,30.0001L 18.75,22.0001L 22,18.7501L 30,26.7501L 30,17.7501L 34,21.7501 Z M 21.75,42L 34,42L 34,54.25L 30,58.25L 30,49.25L 22,57.25L 18.75,54L 26.75,46L 17.75,46L 21.75,42 Z M 42,54.25L 42,42L 54.2499,42L 58.2499,46L 49.2499,46.0001L 57.2499,54L 53.9999,57.25L 45.9999,49.25L 45.9999,58.25L 42,54.25 Z " />
                    <Setter TargetName="FullWindowToolTip" Property="Content" Value="Hide in window" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Controls:WindowBehaviours.Normal" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

`Output`

[image]

Resize, minimize, close.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) or [Modern UI for WPF](http://mui.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I need reorganize the window layout: use customized bar with "- □ ×". Above toolkit maybe don't achieve it.

Comment: That's achievable, take a look at MarkPad which uses MahApps.Metro - http://code52.org/DownmarkerWPF/